# Picklist - Show value not in list

Tags: picklist

Very new to SFDC so please excuse me if I don't use the right terminology.

I have a date field on a form. It shows both historical data and new/current data. The business rule is that if the user can only change the date to a "future" date so the picklist only shows future dates. But when a historical record is loaded, it would need to display the value but it can't since it is not in the picklist.

How is this sort of thing handled? Can the "odd one out" value be shown in the picklist (and saved to the back-end) even though it is technically not part of the valid values for the list?

Comment: I really want you to elaborate the requirement.

Comment: how are you creating the picklist values? is this a list of selectOptions? or are you using OOB fields of type=picklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Workflow rule to set a specific value for a picklist. You can also have additional values available, but not displaying for certain record types.

If you import records and some rows have values being mapped to a picklist which do not currently exist in available picklist values, the value you specify will be added to the record; but will not be available as a new picklist value. I think this is what you were asking...

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. So say the picklist values are 1,2,3,4 and the record has a value of 5. When the record is shown, it will show 5? And allow it to be changed to 1,2,3 or 4? But if the user doesn't change it and saves the record, the 5 will be saved?

Comment: That's correct. 5 will not be available for selection; all other available picklist values for the record type would be available for a user to change it to. If you do an update or insert via data loader, you could literally have any value, say 5-100, which would be stored on those records unless the values are changed by a user to 1,2,3,4